# How can I change the default behavior of Windows Explorer in Windows 7 to open Computer rather than Libraries

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

By default, opening `Windows Explorer` in `Windows 7` opens in `Libraries`. Can I change this behavior and open in `Computer`. It makes navigating into hard drives easier, as I open hard drives frequently than using `Libraries`. I don't wanna turn off Libraries though (they are gr8 at what they do). Any idea to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Right-click the Explorer icon
- Right-click the `Windows Explorer`
  entry on the jump list
- Choose `Properties`
- In the Target box, enter `%windir%\explorer.exe ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`

Comment: u r terribly awesome man! thnx

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the Explorer icon and choose Properties. In the Target box, enter:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n,/e, c:\
```

This opens Explorer in the root of the `C:` drive.

To open it in My Computer, enter this:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a setting that does this however, if you use the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut key it will open My Computer by default, and I use this way more often then the icon.