# Change default location for Explorer opened via hotkey

Tags: windows-explorer, hotkeys

My searching has only shown me how to change various `shortcuts` for Windows Explorer to open specific locations. While learning the command line options for explorer.exe is beneficial, I'm trying to change where Windows Explorer opens when opening it by hitting <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (the shortcut)-

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/111323/how-can-i-change-the-default-behavior-of-windows-explorer-in-windows-7-to-open-c) Super User question was particularly informative on the subject, but again - for shortcuts, not when using the global hotkey.

Why do I want this? <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is by far my favorite; why to open Window's explorer? But, most of the time I want to see my userdir. Also, I detest the favorites, libraries, and desktop/user directory shown (Why? because they don't represent the filesystem), it should only be computer/* <- This I've done. I want <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open to be `{install_drive}/users/{user}`, e.g. `c:/users/payo`.

Comment: Why not run a cmd file, like a batch file?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @MartyFried you mean, to remap win+r to my own path? Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @ekaj because I prefer it go to my custom path, it seems like something I should be able to do. Should I concoct a more legitimate justification that this for my question than simply, "because i want to, that's why"?

Comment: @MartyFried I had a typo, which may have confused everyone, I meant win+e, not win+r

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry I couldn't help.  @ikaj, really?  To map a command to run explorer with a path, like what he asked for, I thought at the time.  Don't you know how to use them?

Comment: Using the registry. [How to Change WinKey + E Shortcut Target in Windows 10?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/winkey-e-shortcut-target-change/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LikeHacker has an article entitled: '[Make Win+E Open the Folder of Your Choice](http://lifehacker.com/5300059/make-win%252Be-open-the-folder-of-your-choice)'

It uses [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) which is a very helpful tool if you like to use your keyboard.

The line that works for me in the Autohotkey.ahk file is:

```
#e::Run, explore %USERPROFILE%
```

Comment: to be honest, i was hoping this would amount to a regedit. This is a solution though, and for that I thank you.

Comment: Small downside of this solution is that it doesn't change the behaviour of clicking `Explorer` in your taskbar. It's more of a "slap a plaster on top" kind of solution, whereas `@Susanne`'s registry mod is more of a "rewire the circuit" method. But at the end of the day it's your computer so do what you want.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows 7, it works this way:

1. Open `regedit`, and navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow
   ```
2. Rename the sub-key `command` to `command.old`, because we can't use it. (Its default value type is `REG_SZ` and we need a `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.)
3. Open a Command Prompt window (`cmd`) as Administrator, to create a new key with a default value type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. (This is not possible via `regedit`.)
4. Type the following line and change `C:\your\folder` to your needs. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   ```
   reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /root, C:\your\folder"
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and Explorer opens at `C:\your\folder`.

Comment: Why not just create a new key directly in Registry Editor GUI for steps 3 and 4? Instructions should preferably take the easier route of simply clicking a few things on a GUI. Advanced users (terminal-buffs) will be smart enough to convert them into commands or scripts but novices should not be expected to meddle with command prompts and not mess up.

Comment: It's not possible to use the Registry Editor GUI to create a key with a default value type REG_EXPAND_SZ. So you have to take the way via a command line.

Comment: Wow, that is strange. `REG_SZ` doesn't work for this tip **at all** while `REG_EXPAND_SZ` works. What is the reason? Btw, it could also be `%windir%\explorer.exe`; that's what I used instead of `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe`.

Comment: "According to the Microsoft Developer's Network (MSDN), the REG_EXPAND_SZ registry value is 'a null-terminated string that contains unexpanded references to environment variables (for example, "%PATH%"). It will be a Unicode or ANSI string depending on whether you use the Unicode or ANSI functions.'" -- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271733/en-us

Comment: If that is the case, then shouldn't the expanded form in `REG_SZ` work? But it doesn't. Besides I have used environment variables in other registry hacks without having to change to `REG_EXPAND_SZ` so I think this goes deeper than that. Anyway, good to know. Always learning something!

Comment: The `/root` parameter seems to cause the following problem: the opened window does start at the specified location, but subsequent folder navigation opens a second window instead of using the current one. Removing the `/root` flag (including the coma, but not what is following) seems to solve this.

Comment: Remove `, /root` and change your path to `::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}` and you'll get explorer opening to your home dir which will also be treated as the root path in the address bar/breadcrumbs (tested in win10).  I cannot comprehend how this is not the default behavior in 2017, let alone absent as a default-UI-supported option.  And personally, I like having text commands I can use - I find them easier and certaingly faster than mucking with GUI navigation of the registry.

Comment: Thank you, @Susanne. Confirmed that this still works in Windows 10 20H2 to change the hotkey and default File Explorer taskbar icon to open to any desired folder. Especially handy given that Microsoft only offers either "Quick access" or "This PC" in Folder Options > General > "Open File Explorer to:".

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way to change to `My Computer`. (Not a custom location)

I'm using Windows 10 Redstone.

[image: Windows Key + E location]

Comment: It is certainly an improvement to not open "Quick access".

Answer (score -1):

- Right click on folder on taskbar,
- Right click on Explorer
- Choose: *Properties*
- Paste this:

  ```
  "%windir%\explorer.exe " /e,c:
  ```

  or this

  ```
  "%windir%\explorer.exe " /e,d:
  ```