# How to start Windows 7 Explorer in any folder using Windows-E shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it possible to launch Windows 7 Explorer using Windows-E shortcut and make it start in  any custom folder by default (**without** third-party tools)?

Right now it opens "Computer"..

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set up a default folder for Windows Explorer?](http://superuser.com/questions/70161/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-default-folder-for-windows-explorer)

Comment: No, it is not. my question relates to Windows 7, not XP.

Comment: related question: http://superuser.com/q/421325/3719, the answer there requires a third party tool though.

Comment: @Temuri yes it is, solution is the same for W7 as it is for XP

Comment: @Moab No, it does not work. Please provide precise instructions if you managed to get it done.

Comment: Post by JMD in the duplicate had this link...http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/customize-the-windows-e-key-shortcut-to-open-what-you-want/1188

Comment: The whole point of SU is to not post duplicate questions and answers, the info is there if you wish to find it. This is not a forum, read the FAQ

Comment: Does it have to be the `Win` + `E`? Or would a shortcut with a programmed shortcut key work? With the shortcut key option you could have several combinations without changing the default.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the class codes in the Registry.

But not the best idea. Better to create a new hotkey like Win+H to go to home directory or whatever... Use the 3rd party App and run Procmon.. It will tell you what goes on. So you dont need to rely on that.